# Special chars getting lost in $_POST

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

In a project we have a form with some `input` fields and a `textarea`. 
It is a multilangual project and if some text is translated in German the use of chars like ü and ö are very common.

In the past we never had problems saving and retrieving these from a database.
We use the `utf8_general_ci` collation in our tables.

Today we got a strange behaviour when submitting the form.
All special chars entered in the `input` fields seem to dissapear.
(They are even gone in $_POST['field_name'], at first we thought it had something to do with codeigniter's input class)

However, any special chars entered in the `textarea` ARE in the `$_POST`array...

Did anyone have this problem before?

Comment: Can you verify that your entire chain is UTF-8? (meta tags, SET NAMES etc.)

Comment: Have you checked the collation of the individual columns in the table.  Sometimes it can be set to different to the table.  e.g. can you insert characters directly from a database query?  If you can then that narrows it down on the input rather than the database.

Comment: The individual colums all are the same collation. The meta tags get set depending on the language used at time of pageload. First time I saw this though. Not sure if it needs to be like that, but the dude who worked here before me coded that part. Should I change the meta to utf8 for each language ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set meta tag to utf8 or iso-8859-1

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=iso-8859-1"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Add `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` to the header

Comment: `htmlspecialchars` is not the right function. `htmlspecialschars` should be used when _ouputting_ to HTML; not input to the database.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen I was too fast, ment to be Mysql real escape string

Comment: `mysql*_real_escape_string` doesn't do anything with encoding, so yes you should use it but it doesn't solve OPs problem.

Comment: You should not use mysql extension as it's deprecated.

Comment: Setting the UTF-8 Content-Type charset is just one of many encoding hints you can set. Now your answer is partial at best.